# Plot list of list 3 values

Tags: python, pandas, list, matplotlib, plotly

I have this list of lists

```
c = [[[1.0, 1.0000000000000002, 6154.0],
  [2.0, 0.0, 6154.0],
  [3.0, -0.9999999999999997, 6154.0],
  [4.0, 0.3809523809523809, 6154.0],
  [5.0, 0.0, 6154.0]],
 [[1.0, 1.0000000000000002, 3720.0],
  [2.0, 0.07407407407407404, 3720.0],
  [3.0, 1.0, 3720.0],
  [4.0, 1.0, 3720.0]],
 [[1.0, -1.0000000000000009, 17139.0]],
 [[1.0, -1.0000000000000009, 16149.0]],
 [[1.0, 1.0, 4075.0], [2.0, -0.999999999999999, 4075.0]],
 [[1.0, 0.0, 21445.0],
  [2.0, 1.0000000000000002, 21445.0],
  [3.0, 0.0, 21445.0],
  [4.0, 0.9999999999999998, 21445.0],
  [5.0, 0.0, 21445.0],
  [6.0, 1.0, 21445.0],
  [7.0, 0.0, 21445.0]]]
```

For each list, I would like to plot a scatter plot using the first two values and use the third for the legend.  When I have just two value so in this case:

```
c1 = c = [[[1.0, 1.0000000000000002],
  [2.0, 0.0],
  [3.0, -0.9999999999999997],
  [4.0, 0.3809523809523809],
  [5.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0, 1.0000000000000002],
  [2.0, 0.07407407407407404],
  [3.0, 1.0],
  [4.0, 1.0]],
 [[1.0, -1.0000000000000009]],
 [[1.0, -1.0000000000000009]],
 [[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, -0.999999999999999]],
 [[1.0, 0.0],
  [2.0, 1.0000000000000002],
  [3.0, 0.0],
  [4.0, 0.9999999999999998],
  [5.0, 0.0],
  [6.0, 1.0],
  [7.0, 0.0]]]
```

I am able to plot the list of lists using the following code:

```
for i in c1:
    plt.plot(*zip(*i), 'o-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I modify the code above? To reach the same result but using the third value for the legend? Or do you know how can I use plotly.express to make the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With plotly `figure`, you can loop through the list and plot each sublist separately with a `name`:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.Figure()
for lst in c:
    x, y, g = zip(*lst)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name=g[0]))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I dont know the plotly part, but this is to display legend on plot:

```
c1 = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y[:2], x)), c))
legend = list(map(lambda x: x[0][-1], c))
for i, lbl in zip(c1, legend):
    plt.plot(*zip(*i), 'o-', label=lbl)
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a much simpler way:

```
for i in c:
    plt.plot(*zip(*[j[:2] for j in i] ), 'o-')
plt.gca().legend([i[0][2] for i in c])
plt.show()
```

You can access the instance of the axes with plt.gca(). I have used a list comprehension to retrieve the values for plotting and for the legend from the original list `c`.
Below is the resultant graph with legend:[image]